# Change code to use parameters

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I'm trying to change this code so that I can use parameters for freight and handling in suitescript 2.0. Here's my code:

/** 
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType UserEventScript
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
*/
define(["N/record", "N/log", "N/runtime"], function (record, log, runtime) {

```
function afterSubmit(context) {

    // Gather your variables
    var newRec = context.newRecord;
    var freightCost = newRec.getValue({
        fieldId: 'custbody_freight_cost'
    });
    var salesOrderId = newRec.getValue({
        fieldId: 'createdfrom'
    });
    log.debug('Sales Order ID', salesOrderId);
    log.error({
        title: 'Freight Cost',
        details: freightCost
    });

    // Transform the Sales Order into an Invoice
    var invoiceRecord = record.transform({
        fromType: record.Type.SALES_ORDER,
        fromId: salesOrderId,
        toType: record.Type.INVOICE,
        isDynamic: true
    });
    log.error({
        title: 'Debug Entry',
        details: invoiceRecord
    });
    invoiceRecord.selectNewLine({
        sublistId: 'item'
    });
    invoiceRecord.setCurrentSublistText({
        sublistId: 'item',
        fieldId: 'item',
        text: 'FREIGHT'
    });
    invoiceRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
        sublistId: 'item',
        fieldId: 'amount',
        value: freightCost
    });
    invoiceRecord.commitLine({
        sublistId: 'item'
    });
    invoiceRecord.selectNewLine({
        sublistId: 'item'
    });
    invoiceRecord.setCurrentSublistText({
        sublistId: 'item',
        fieldId: 'item',
        text: 'HANDLING'
    });
    invoiceRecord.commitLine({
        sublistId: 'item'
    });

    // Here is how you set a body field
    invoiceRecord.setValue({
        fieldId: 'custbody_freight_cost',
        value: freightCost,
        ignoreFieldChange: true
    });

    // Submit the record
    var rid = invoiceRecord.save();
    log.debug('Saved Record', rid);
}
return {
    afterSubmit: afterSubmit 
    };
```

});

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to create the appropriate Script Parameters on your Script record, populate the appropriate values on your Script Deployment record, then leverage `N/runtime.getParameter()` to retrieve those values at runtime.